# How to do math operations with model fields or expressions in Agile Toolkit

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

atk4.2.1

I have this model:

```
class Model_Cargo extends Model_Table {
public $table='cargo';
function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Alumno');
    $this->hasOne('Plan');

    $this->addField('fecha')->type('date');
    $this->addField('fechaCreacion')->type('date');
    $this->addField('fechaVencimiento')->type('date');
    $this->addField('name');
    $this->addField('monto')->type('money');
    $this->addField('cancelado')->type('boolean')->defaultValue(false);

    $this->hasMany('Abono');
    $this->addExpression('abonos')->set($this->refSQL('Abono')->sum('monto'));
   }
}
```

I wanto to make a math operation + or - with two fields:
I actually want to substracr field 'monto' with expression 'abonos' how do I do it?

lets say something like this:

```
$this->addExpression('balance')->set('monto'-'abonos');
//this does not work
```

I also wold like to addCondition where those fields are equal... can I do that?

something lke:

```
$this->addCondition('monto','abonos');
//this does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example illustrating how to use calculated fields in expressions:

http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/model/def

For your problem, you would need something like this:

```
$this->addExpression('balance')->set(function($m,$q){
    return $q->expr('[f1] - [f2]')
        ->setCustom('f1',$m->getElement('monto'))
        ->setCustom('f2',$m->getElement('abonos'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->addExpression("balance")->set("monto - abonos");` and that's it - sql expression.

then you can:

`$this->addCondition("balance", ">", 0);` or whatever you need.

Comment: It doesn't work, it's ok for the field, but not for the expression, this is the optput:  
pdo_error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'abonos' in 'field list'
mode: select
params: Array ( )
query: select (select `name` from `alumno` where `cargo`.`alumno_id` = `alumno`.`id` ) `alumno`,(select `name` from `plan` where `cargo`.`plan_id` = `plan`.`id` ) `plan`,`fecha`,`fechaVencimiento`,`name`,`monto`,`cancelado`,`fechaCreacion`,(select sum(`monto`) from `abono` where `abono`.`cargo_id` = `cargo`.`id` ) `abonos`,monto - abonos `balance`,`id`,`fechaCancelacion` from `cargo`

Comment: it's because abonos is not a column but calculated field as well. you have to put full query in set("..") for balance field.